# Parsing a string in c++ like python's parse package

Tags: python, c++, stl

In python, I use `parse` from the `parse` package so if I have `001-044.mp4`, I can just use a template `{}-{}.mp4` and pass that to `parse` and iterate over 2 result elements to get `001` and `004`. 
I would like a similar counter part in c++ in such a case where I have to parse a string depending on several such separators. Any pointers?

Comment: Create one yourself, or use an existing library/regex. Not sure what kind of pointers you are looking for. Please also note that questions without any code is usually not well received here. Especially if you are asking people to show/write code as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how complicated your example is, consider looking at [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) or [`regex`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/). Neither follows the pythonic syntax, but can be used to do the same thing.

Using sscanf:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
  const char* text = "012-231.mp4";

  int a = 0, b = 0;
  sscanf(text, "%d-%d.mp4", &a, &b);

  printf("First number: %d, second number: %d\n", a, b);
}
```

Using regex:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string text = "012-231.mp4";

  std::regex expr("([0-9]*)-([0-9]*).mp4");

  std::smatch match;
  std::regex_match(text, match, expr);

  std::cout << "The matches are: ";
  // Start from i = 1; the first match is the entire string
  for (unsigned i = 1; i < match.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << match[i] << ", ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

If you are looking for something that behaves strictly like the python format function, you'll probably have to write your own.